# VS2008 Professional trial does not show x64 option

Tags: visual-studio-2008, 64-bit

I've VS2008 Professional trial obn windows 7 64 bit installed at the moment and its not giving me any other  option other than Win32. Creating x64 nmanually doesnt work, 64 bit compiler are there. Driving me nuts..
Need the service pack?
http://www.visualstudiodev.com/visual-studio-setup-installation/cant-create-x64-configurations-compile-existing-projects-using-one-231.shtml

Answer (score 0):

installing service pack 1 helped